# Why are extra line breaks added from stored textarea data sent from a form

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have a Textarea with this in it:

```
Test can't talk<br />
Test
```

When I send it to my preview page I use this:

```
$Comments = htmlspecialchars("$_POST[CustComments]", ENT_QUOTES);
$Comments = str_replace("\n","<br />", $Comments);
```

It then shows this on the preview page:

```
Test can't talk<br />
Test
```

When I go back to edit it, in the edit page code I have this.

```
$Comments = str_replace("<br />","\n", $_POST['CustComments']);
$Comments = htmlspecialchars($Comments, ENT_QUOTES);
```

But it shows this:

```
Test can't talk

Test
```

Where is this extra break coming from and how do I get rid of it?

---

**UPDATE:**
Per a suggestion on the edit page I have this.

```
$Comments = htmlspecialchars($_POST['CustComments'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

And that shows this:

```
Test can't talk
<br />Test
```

Again where is this extra `<br />` coming from? If I use `strreplace` it will show like this

```
Test can't talk

Test
```

Using just this:

```
$Comments = nl2br($_POST['CustComments']);
```

It shows this:

```
Test can't talk<br />
<br />Test
```

Again a random `<br />` is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the view page need to use this:

```
$Comments = htmlspecialchars("$_POST[CustComments]", ENT_QUOTES);
$Comments = str_replace("\r\n","<br />",$Comments);
```

On the edit page use this:

```
$Comments = str_replace("<br />","\n",$_POST['CustComments'])
```

On the submission page:

```
function keepSafe($value) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }
    return $value;
}
$Comments = keepSafe($_POST['CustComments']);
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: This worked for the time needed. Since standards change and get_magic_quotes_gpc has become depreciated I have found the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using str_replace()? Try this instead:

```
$Comments = nl2br($Comments);
```